# Windows Phone 8.1 RT - Navigating from two different pages to shared one

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to make three pages: Page1 (P1), Page2 (P2) and EditPage(EP), and I would like to navigate from P1 and P2 to EP. Is there a way to recognize if I navigate from P1 or P2?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Parameter when navigatins between pages.

When navigating from Page 1:

```
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditPage), "Page1");
```

When navigating from Page 2:

```
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditPage), "Page2");
```

Afterwards, you must override OnNavigatedTo method:

```
public sealed partial class EditPage : Page
{
    public EditPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (e.Parameter.ToString() == "Page1")
        {
            //Navigated from Page1
        }

        if(e.Parameter.ToString() == "Page2")
        {
            //Navigated from Page2
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest reading some basics articles on msdn about Page Navigation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx

Comment: I knew about it. I was wondering if it is another way to check it because I already have parameter to pass.

Comment: Just create new Class and add as many fields as you want. And when just pass the object of this class as a parameter.